# Get large string from database

Tags: database, postgresql, character-encoding

I have large string in my postgresql database. It's a base64 encoded mp3 and I have to select the column with that large string and get all the data with one select. If I write normal select

```
SELECT * FROM public.song_data WHERE id=1;
```

it will return just 204 kB from that string and the string has 2.2 MB.

Also the datagrip shows me just 204 kB of data from that string. Is there a way to get all the data with just one select?

Comment: Try `SELECT length(bytea_column) FROM public.song_data WHERE id=1`. If that is 2.2MB, then your client is not displaying the whole thing. If it is shorter, there was a problem storing the value.

Comment: Are you sure datagrip is not cutting off long strings for performance reasons?

Answer (score 1):

It's strange. Are you sure so your data was not trimmed somewhere? You can use function `length` for check of actual size.

```
postgres=# select length('aaa');
┌────────┐
│ length │
╞════════╡
│      3 │
└────────┘
(1 row)
```

Two MB are nothing for Postgres, but some clients (or protocols) can problem with it. Sometimes is necessary to use functions `lo_import` and `lo_export` as workaround for client / protocol limits. For selecting data from table you should to use `SELECT` statement. There is not any other way. Theoretically you can transform any string to large object and then by function `lo_export` you can download this large object from database with LO special protocol. For 2MB it should not be necessary I think.

Please, try to check if your data was stored to postgres correctly. Theoretical limit for text, varchar is 1GB. Practical limit is less value - about 100MB. It is significantly higher value than 2MB.

Postgres has special data type for binary data - `bytea`. It does conversation to hex code by default and base64 encoding is supported too.

Answer (score 0):

You can select number of chars you want to show using `left` with negative values (which removes characters from the end) and `concat`:

```
SELECT left(concat(public.song_data,' '), -1) from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

The client was actually the problem. Datagrip can’t print of 2MB. I tried another client (DBeaver and Heidisql) and it was ok. Then I selected a row of 2MB with a php select and I got all that data.